# calling setCoordinate on MKPlacemark crashes app with 'unrecognized selector'

Tags: objective-c, mkmapview, mkannotation, mkplacemark

I have a MKMapView i'm adding a single MKPlacemark to to represent the location of a building the user has just selected.  The user can only select one building at a time, and I simply want to move the placemark to the new building when they select a new building.  On the first building they select, it works fine and places a pin on the map.  When I try and call `setCoordinate` on the placemark to update the position of the marker when they select a new building though, I get `-[MKPlacemark setCoordinate:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`

In MyViewController.h I have:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong)MKPlacemark *selectedBuildingPlacemark;
```

In MyViewController.m

```
@synthesize selectedBuildingPlacemark;

...

if (self.selectedBuildingPlacemark == nil) {
        self.selectedBuildingPlacemark = [[MKPlacemark alloc] initWithCoordinate:myCoord addressDictionary:nil];
        [mapView addAnnotation:self.selectedBuildingPlacemark];
    }
    else {
        [self.selectedBuildingPlacemark setCoordinate:myCoord];
    }
```

I thought MKPlacemark conformed to MKAnnotation and should therefore implement `setCoordinate`.  Can someone show me the error of my ways?

Comment: Where are you setting myCoord?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation of [`MKAnnotation`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKAnnotation_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008208-CH1-SW1) says:

> Annotations that support dragging should implement this method to update the position of the annotation.

So the method `setCoordinate:` is optional and is only implemented by classes that support dragging. The documentation of [`MKPlacemark`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKPlacemark_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008322-CH1-DontLinkElementID_4) does not reference that method, so it is not implemented.

So you should create a new instance every time you select a new building.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't specifically need to use an `MKPlacemark` (it doesn't look like it because you're passing nil for the addressDictionary), you could use the `MKPointAnnotation` class instead.

`MKPointAnnotation` implements `MKAnnotation` but adds a `setCoordinate` method.